# Difference between object creations JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there - if any - difference between these two instantiations? What is the difference if it exists?

First:

```
function MyClass() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.initialise = function () { console.log('initialised'); }

    return vm; //<-- here
}
```

Second:

```
function MyClass() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.initialise = function () { console.log('initialised'); }

    //<-- here
}
```

Usage:

```
var newClass = new MyClass();
```

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't think there is when using the `new` keyword.

Comment: @SecondRikudo, you're right. After reading the spec again everything seems to work fine even if `this` is aliased in the constructor and the alias is returned.

Comment: @DavidBarker I'm halfway through writing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `new` keyword, a constructor function function will return `this` by default.

Since your two options are "Use the default return value" and "Explicitly return `this`", there is no difference between the two approaches.

---

The idiomatic approach would be to not have an explicit return value, but to also not create `vm` in the first place and to just reference `this` directly.

Comment: Cheers, didn't think there were, chrome console don't show a difference